# How to use register_forward_hook on ScriptModules

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to use register_forward_hook on ScriptModules.
currently ScriptModules is not support register_forward_hook.
So, my plan is that

1. convert scriptModules to nn.Module
2. register forward hook on converted nn.Module

Can I get to know the above is possible?